# SSH Tunnel: channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited

Tags: centos, ssh, tunnel, socks

I have two servers, let's say server A and server B. I wish to use server B as an ssh tunnel so on server A I did this

```
ssh -D 1080 root@ip
```

It connects and as soon as I put in the server B as a SOCKS5 proxy on my server A, the server B comes up with this erorr:

```
channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited
```

Some how if I get server B from a host like vultr, I don't get this error but if I get it from digitalocean I get this error. I did some research and saw I should allowtcpforwarding to be yes but I could not find it in /etc/ssh/ssh_config

This is my ssh_config file:

```
# Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
```

Would appreciate if someone could tell me what am I doing wrong :3

Answer (score 3):

The config file you need to edit is called `sshd_config` you wrote `ssh_config`. What you have listed looks like the contents of the ssh client default configuration, not the config for the ssh server (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config)`

Answer (score 1):

What you list is just the default values, commented out.

So you can add, below a `Host *` something like:

> AllowTcpForwarding local

Note that yes should be the default, so it is strange it does not work. You can add more verbosity with `ssh -v` or `-vv` or `-vvv` and have a look at your server sshd logfile that should provide more information on what is wrong.

Comment: Nope still can't get it to work, I added that line but it reproduces the same error.

Comment: What do you have in logfiles?

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to set `AllowTcpForwarding yes` in the `sshd_config` on the server to allow this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

First, check for entries in `/var/log/secure` for something like this;

```
Feb  1 19:59:58 vps001 sshd[30375]: error: connect_to 
www.somenonexistingdomain.com: unknown host (Name or service not known)
```

second, check whether selinux is blocking; (if you are RedHat based))

```
$ sudo ausearch -m avc -c httpd
----
time->Sat Jan  6 08:58:11 2018
type=AVC msg=audit(1515229091.030:7212): avc:  denied  { map } for  pid=20581 comm="httpd" path="/var/
```

you can test and disable selinux like so;

```
[~] $ sudo getenforce
Enforcing

[~] $ sudo setenforce Permissive

[~] $ sudo getenforce
Permissive
```

then test and see if it is now working.

```
[~] $ sudo setenforce Enforcing
```

I get the `open failed: administratively prohibited` behaviour if the server cannot connect to the site you are requesting on the other side.

For example, if I send a request for `www.somenotexistingdomain.com` via a socks 5 proxy `ssh -S none  -D1083 -vvv  my.cheap.vps.com`, it results in this output;

```
debug1: Connection to port 1083 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug2: fd 10 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: fd 10 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 10 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 4: new [dynamic-tcpip]
....
debug2: channel 4: dynamic request: socks5 host www.somenonexistingdomain.com port 80 command 1
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug3: receive packet: type 92
channel 4: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
debug2: channel 4: zombie
debug2: channel 4: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 4: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 1083 for www.somenonexistingdomain.com port 80, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 42598 to 127.0.0.1 port 1083, nchannels 22
```

and you can see that it cannot connect.

If you are sure that the server you are trying to access exists; For example, first test that you can `wget` or `curl` the site from the command line remotely.

```
$ wget -S -O - www.bbc.co.uk > /dev/null
Resolving www.bbc.co.uk (www.bbc.co.uk)... 212.58.244.69, 212.58.246.93
Connecting to www.bbc.co.uk (www.bbc.co.uk)|212.58.244.69|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
```

If that doesn't work, then its possible that if you are forwarding to the proxy DNS, is that the remote server cannot resolve the DNS. So check that;

```
$ dig www.bbc.co.uk +short
www.bbc.net.uk.
212.58.246.91
212.58.244.67
```

and also check direct connection to the port using netcat, telnet etc. however pulling the site with wget should have tested both tcp connection and DNS.

```
$ telnet www.bbc.co.uk 80
Trying 212.58.244.26...
Connected to www.bbc.co.uk.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

and definitely check the entries in the /var/log/secure file.

Failing that turn logging right up (`ssh -vvvvvvv`) and watch both sides of the connection.